# Next.js Route: Dynamic vs exact

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I'm new to Next.js and I'm curious what will happen if, for example, I have these two routes where one is dynamic, and one is as-is, and both were almost named the same:

```
/posts/[id]
/posts/latest
```

I'm thinking if they will clash with one another? And if they do, then how will Next.JS differentiate that the `/latest` is not a parameter for `/[id]`?

Comment: Because you can add `id` params to the url. `https://www.google.com/search?q=italy` if you paste this to your browser, you will get the google search result of Italy. And as you can see that where `italy` is in the link. So, if you type like `america`, america search result will be up. Basically, you must add `id` param to your http request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next.js handles it internally, it's completely fine to use a predefined route  `/posts/latest` with a dynamic route `/posts/[id]`. In this case `/posts/latest` will always take precedence over the dynamic route.

From the [dynamic routes documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats):

> Predefined routes take precedence over dynamic routes, and dynamic
> routes over catch all routes. Take a look at the following examples:
>
> - `pages/post/create.js` - Will match `/post/create`
> - `pages/post/[pid].js` -
>   Will match `/post/1`, `/post/abc`, etc. But not `/post/create`
> - `pages/post/[...slug].js` - Will match `/post/1/2`, `/post/a/b/c`, etc. But
>   not `/post/create`, `/post/abc`